# How can I print out blocked clients in color in the console using C

Tags: c, windows, file, winapi, formatting

I am trying to print out all clients in different color. The ones that have not the status 'blocked' in normal white color, and those who have the status 'blocked' should be printed out in color red in the console. However I have some formatting, like '—' em dashes and I cannot come by them, meaning I want to print out the blocked clients from the word 'BLOCKED' with the color red until the last em dash line, not 'Date of reg:' like its happening now.

```
           BLOCKED
         Client ID: 05300
—————————————————————————————————————
Name: ABC
—————————————————————————————————————
Last: DEF
—————————————————————————————————————
Date of reg: 22-12-2023 18:46:13   <-- this is where the color red ends
————————————————————————————————————  <-- but I want it to end here

//And this client is printed out in normal white color since he does not have status 'blocked'
        Client ID: 05796
—————————————————————————————————————
Name: ERT
—————————————————————————————————————
Last: TYU
—————————————————————————————————————
Date of reg: 22-12-2023 18:49:22
—————————————————————————————————————
```

I am saving the inputted data into a file like this:

```
fprintf(file, "\n        Client ID: %05d\n", rand() % 10000);
fprintf(file, "—————————————————————————————————————\n");
fprintf(file, "Name: %s\n", name);
fprintf(file, "—————————————————————————————————————\n");
fprintf(file, "Last: %s\n", last);
fprintf(file, "—————————————————————————————————————\n");
fprintf(file, "Date of reg: %s\n", formatted_date);
fprintf(file, "—————————————————————————————————————\n");
```

And then I read it from it:

```
    char line[100];
    bool blocked= false;
    rewind(file);
     
    printf("\nPRINTING OUT ALL CLIENTS:\n\n");
    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), file))
    {
        if (strstr(line, "           BLOCKED") != NULL)
            blocked = true;

        
        if (blocked)
        {
            SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);
            printf("%s", line);
        }
        else
        {
            SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_GREEN | 
            FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);
            printf("%s", line);
        }

        if (strstr(line, "Date of reg:") != NULL)  //here is the problem
        {  
            blocked= false;        
        } 
        /* if(strstr(line, "—————————————————————————————————————" != NULL)
               blocked = false; */  this does not help
    }
}
```

So how can I print out the blocked clients with the color  red until the last ————————————————————————————————————— em dash with the color red ?

Comment: Is the number of lines to print red after the "BLOCKED" line always the same? If yes, then you can set the value of a counter variable to those number of lines, whenever you encounter "BLOCKED". As long as that counter is above zero, all lines will be printed red, and when the counter reaches zero, all lines will be printed black. After every red line printed, the counter should be decremented. That way, you don't have to check for "Date of reg:".

Comment: Yes the number of lines are always the same (37)

Comment: [Console Virtual Terminal Sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a variable when you get to the `Date of reg:` line to indicate that you've reached the end of a client. Then check this after printing a divider line.

```
    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), file))
    {
        if (strstr(line, "           BLOCKED") != NULL) {
            blocked = true;

        SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, FOREGROUND_RED | (blocked ? 0 : FOREGROUND_GREEN) | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);
        printf("%s", line);
 
        if (strstr(line, "Date of reg:") != NULL)
        {  
            end_of_client = true;        
        } 

        if(end_of_client && strstr(line, "—————————————————————————————————————" != NULL) {
            blocked = false;
            end_of_client = false;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. For some reason comparing the current line with em dashes with strstr did not worked at all. But comparing it to an number of lines in line with strncmp does work.



`if (strstr(line, "Date of reg:") != NULL)
                eoc = true;
             
            if(eoc && strncmp(line, "—————————————————————————————————————", 37) == 0) 
            {
                blocked = false;
                eoc = false;
            }`

Comment: Maybe you have too many dashes in the string.